# jQuery scroll to element not working 2

Tags: jquery

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6677069), I have the following after my `<body>`:

```
<a name="Pagetop"></a>
```

In my footer, I have:

```
<script>
    jQuery(".pgtop").click(function() {
        jQuery('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: jQuery("#Pagetop").offset().top
        }, 2000);
    });
</script>
<p class="pgtop"><img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?>/images/up-arrow.png" alt ="Go to top of page" title ="Go to top of page" width="50" height="29" border = "0" ></p>
```

but the scroll to top does not work on [this staging site](http://staging.insightdesign.com.au/).

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your page-top target element to use `id` instead of `name` property

`<a id="Pagetop"></a>`

Also, wait for your page to load before binding the element.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(".pgtop").click(function () {
        jQuery('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: jQuery("#Pagetop").offset().top
        }, 2000);
    });
});
```

Comment: Added a second part

Comment: Excellent, that did it, appreciated Angus.