# jQuery scroll to element not working 3

Tags: jquery

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50402885/667903), I have the following after my `<body>` tag:

```
<a id="Pagetop"></a>
```

In my footer, I have:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery(".pgtop").click(function () {
            jQuery('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: jQuery("#Pagetop").offset().top
            }, 1000);
        });
    });
</script>
<p class="pgtop"><img src=".../images/up-arrow.png" alt ="Go to top of page" title ="Go to top of page" width="30" height="auto" border = "0" ></p>
```

This code works on [this site](http://staging.insightdesign.com.au), but the same code does not work on [this site](http://brand.staging.insightdesign.com.au/).

Can you please see why the up arrow doesn't scroll up on the 2nd site?

The element in question is the up arrow in the bottom right corner of the window.

Help appreciated.

Comment: It works when `html` doesn't have `overflow-y: scroll;` CSS property.

I wish I could explain but I dunno why either...

Comment: That's good enough for me @JacobGoh, add an answer and I'll accept it. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works when `html` doesn't have `overflow-y: scroll;` CSS property.

I wish I could explain but I dunno why either...

Comment: Hi Jacob, can you see why the scroll up arrow doesn't work on [this site](http://digital.staging.insightdesign.com.au/) after I removed `overflow-y: scroll;` from `html`?

Comment: @Steve It works when i executed `jQuery('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            }, 1000);` in the console.

Comment: Thanks Jacob, I replaced the jQuery code with your new code on [that site](http://digital.staging.insightdesign.com.au/) but it doesn't fire when `.pgtop` is clicked on. (line 1314 is where the jQuery is)